# Using Union to prove a context-free language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, fake-proofs

I am working through many examples and I seem to have confused myself and made all the questions rather trivial.

If I have the CFLs, 
$L_1 = \{1^n 0^{mn} : n,m \in \Bbb N\}$ and $L_2 = \{1^m 0^n : m,n \in N\}$.

Could I not use the union property and union it $L_1$ with $L_2$ to equal $L_2$?
Then since $L_2$ is a context-free grammar then, then both $L_1$ and $L_2$ must be?

I feel like I have made and error and made it trivial. It seems like I can do this for everything now.

Thank you!

Comment: I agree that $L_1 \cup L_2 = L_2$, which happens because $L_1 \subset L_2$. Both are CFL -- but what new information does this give you? What are you trying to conclude that you don't know before your union argument?

Comment: $L_1$ is not context-free, however I believe that above I just proved that it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That CFL is preserved under union means, if $L,M$ are CFL, so is $L \cup M$. But you are using this the other way -- if $M$ and $M \cup L$ are CFL, so $L$ must be as well. This is not true, as your counterexample illustrates.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Does this mean I will have to use the pumping lemma to show $L_1$ is not context free?

Comment: @sci1991 yes, that is the usual way